# Python's counter() function is too slow

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am using Django REST framework and there is a post API that I am facing speed issue in the line where i am using Counter() function.

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def calculate_stuff(request):
  t1 = time.time()
  machine_type = request.data['machine_type']
  machine_nos = Machine.objects.filter(machine_type=machine_type).values_list('machine_no', flat=True)
  query = Performance.objects.filter(Q(power=100) | Q(power=192),machine_no__in=machine_nos,
                ).values_list("machine_no", "power")
  t2 = time.time()
  print t2 - t1 # is around 0.2 seconds 
  count_192_100 = Counter(query) 
  t3 = time.time()
  print t3 - t2 # is around 1.3 seconds
```

The models are like this:

```
class Machine(models.Model):
  machine_type = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=10)
  machine_no = models.IntegerField(null=True)
  store_code = models.IntegerField(null=True)
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
class Performance(models.Model):
  machine_no = models.IntegerField(null=True)
  power = models.IntegerField(null=True)
  store_code = models.IntegerField(null=True) 
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

This project is running on production and due to some reason Foreignkey wasn't used between the two models. What i want to achieve here is First: get the machine_no from "Machine" model of a certain machine_type. Second: I want to get how many times each machine no. had power = 100 and power = 192 in "Performance" Model. 
Additional info: I am using Django 1.11, python 2.7.10, postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t actually think it’s your aggregate counter that is slow, but your query set evaluation ie your data access. See Django ORM QuerySets are what’s know as “lazy”. They can be manipulated but evaluation (actually getting the data) is deferred until some triggering execution context. Here is the docs outlining this: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

> When QuerySets are evaluated¶
>
> Internally, a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and
>   generally passed around without actually hitting the database. No
>   database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate
>   the queryset.

So because of your timeit construct, it just looks like the bottleneck is your aggregate counter, buts it likely not. It’s likely the evaluation of the query set.

There are some tactics for optimization of dB access, they are outlined here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/optimization/

Without knowing a little more, we can’t be more specific. If you wouldn’t mind sharing your dB model and some details about how much data it’s actually getting, I’d be happy to help.

You could run  timeit on a forced evaluation with one of the methods outlined in the article , like using the built in list() on the query set, and have that happen before the counter constructor to know for sure.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the models, This project is running on production and due to some reason Foreignkey wasn't used between the two models. What i want to achieve here is First: get the machine_no from Machine model of a certain machine_type. Second: I want to get each machine_no 's power=192 or 100 counts from Performance model.

Answer (score 1):

Counter isn't what's taking all that time. *Actually running the query* and fetching the results is what's taking all that time. The query doesn't run until you iterate over the QuerySet, which happens when you call `Counter`.

Instead of calling `Counter`, consider having the database do the counting for you.

Comment: I ran the query separately and deleted the counter function, the query takes 0.1 seconds to calculate.

Comment: @jencko: Show the code where you run the query without calling `Counter`. I bet you built the QuerySet without actually doing anything to cause query execution.

Comment: You are right actually. I wasn't doing anything that was causing the query execution. Thanks !! Any suggestion for doing this on DB side ?

Comment: What do you want, a count of rows? `select count(*) from table where a = 1` in Django ORM syntax?

Comment: @PaulBecotte:  I have edited the question and added the models, This project is running on production and due to some reason Foreignkey wasn't used between the two models. What i want to achieve here is First: get the machine_no from Machine model of a certain machine_type. Second: I want to get each machine_no 's power=192 or 100 counts from Performance model.

Answer (score 0):

```
 query = Performance.objects.filter(Q(power=100) | 
    Q(power=192),machine_no__in=machine_nos,
                ).values_list("machine_no", "power")
 count_192_100 = Counter(query)
```

That pulls down an actual object for ever row in the database, deserializes them, then uses hashing to do a count unique on them. Instead, use your database for what its good for-

```
count_192_100 = Performance.objects.filter(Q(power=100) | 
    Q(power=192),machine_no__in=machine_nos,
                ).values_list("machine_no", "power").count()
```

.count() basically does `select COUNT(*) from...`

Of course I should mention this doesn't do QUITE the same thing as your query- Counter uses hashing to count unique values! If it is possible that you may have duplicate rows in that table you want `select COUNT(DISTINCT *) FROM ...` which you can do with

```
count_192_100 = Performance.objects.filter(Q(power=100) | 
    Q(power=192),machine_no__in=machine_nos,
                ).values_list("machine_no", "power").distinct().count()
```